# wxPython and localisation

Tags: localization, wxpython

I'd like to write a wxPython application that would run in different languages, updating itself automatically (with no need to close it and open it back) whenever I change the language.
Is it possible to make a system that recognises and edits every widget that needs to be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is prebuilt facility or events in wxPython to trigger such change, but yes it is possible to write a system of your own e.g. you can have a central registry where each control which needs translation registers and when language changes you notify all those controls. It will be the responsibility of individual control to translate and update itself correctly.

Also see http://wiki.wxpython.org/RecipesI18n

Comment: I'm not sure if you can change language on the fly with wxPython'x getTranslation() methods

Answer (score 0):

I did it in that way
created property file for each language  and store translations into this file.

Translation config with UTF8 encoding

```
config = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
config.readfp(codecs.open(fileName, "r", "utf8"))
```

translation looks like:

```
Time & Date=Время и дата
Time=Время
Local time=Местное время
```